# Pyspark dataframe join with a given list of primary keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have doubt whether this can be possible.

Lets speak about my requirement, I have `tableA` with multiple primary keys.

`primary_key: ['user_id', 'role_id']` like this multiple tables are there with more than 2 Pks, all the Pks defined in a json as shown below.

```
{  "sourcetable": "app_setting",
   "schema": "dbo",
    "primarykey": [
                "application_code",
                "region_code",
                "country_code",
                "app_setting_key",
                "app_setting_value"
    ]
}
```

On the same table, I have defined 2 dataframes,

```
Df1 = spark.read.parquet(tableA)    # complete table
df2 = Df1.filter((df1.user_id == 1) & (df1.user_id==1)) # df2 is filter Df
```

Now I want to join these df1 and df2

```
join_Df= Df1.join(df2 , df2[primary_key] == Df1["primary_key"], "inner")
```

But I have got the error:

> in join assert isinstance(on[0], Column), "on should be Column or list of Column" AssertionError: on should be Column or list of Column

Is this join possible with a list of PKs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean composite primary key not multiple pks.

You can simply pass the primary keys as list of strings in join condition:

```
 table_info = {
        "sourcetable": "app_setting", "schema": "dbo",
        "primarykey": ["application_code", "region_code", "country_code", "app_setting_key", "app_setting_value"]
    }

df_result = df1.alias("DF1").join(df2.alias("DF2"), table_info["primarykey"])
```

Or if you prefer to use columns, you can iterate over the list of the column names which compose the pk and create a join condition like this :

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


join_cols = [
    F.col(f"DF1.{c}") == F.col(f"DF2.{c}")
    for c in table_info["primarykey"]
]

df_result = df1.alias("DF1").join(
    df2.alias("DF2"),
    reduce(lambda acc, x: acc & x, join_cols),
    "inner"
)
```

Comment: primary_key = table_parameter['primarykey']df_result = df1.join(df2, primary_key, "leftanti")

Comment: Above code is working but there is a problem if any of the table has list of pks other than string. That means while merging this dataframe with another dataframe facing data incompatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this now and it is some how working but don't know if this is the great answer.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

lst1 = [[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
lst2 = [[2, 3, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]
lst3 = [[1, 2, 4], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']]

R1 = Row("A1", "A2", "A3")
R2 = Row("B1", "B2", "B3")
R3 = Row("C1", "C2", "C3")
df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R1(*r) for r in zip(*lst1)]).toDF().alias('df1')
df2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R2(*r) for r in zip(*lst2)]).toDF().alias('df2')
df3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([R3(*r) for r in zip(*lst3)]).toDF().alias('df3')

list_tup = [(df1, df2, "df1.A1", "df2.B1"),
            (df2, df3, "df2.B1", "df3.C1"),
            (df1, df3, "df1.A1", "df3.C1")]

df_1 = list_tup[0][0]
for x in list_tup:
    df_1 = x[0].join(x[1], on=F.col(x[2]) == F.col(x[3]), how="left_outer")

df_1.show()



+---+---+---+----+----+----+
| A1| A2| A3|  C1|  C2|  C3|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  A| aa|   1|   A|  aa|
|  2|  B| bb|   2|   B|  bb|
|  3|  C| cc|null|null|null|
+---+---+---+----+----+----+
```